# Can I use google app engine to run the python program in the background for chrome extension?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-chrome

I have a python program which has to execute when i click on the chrome extension.Can I use the Google app engine to do the same??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of program is to be executed? You could very well send a request from Chrome extension to your appengine server, process and return the response.